# How do I use prepared statements with SQLite in C# if I need to do a SELECT call between INSERT calls?

Tags: c#, sql, database, sqlite, transactions

I am working on a project that has to enter about 80,000 row entries into a database per run. I've been able to speed it up a lot thanks to prepared statements. However, I am running into a problem where one last area where I need to make a lot of row entries relies on data from SELECT calls made between INSERT statements due to the involvement of foreign keys. In all of the examples I have seen of prepared statements, it was all for ExecuteNonQuery() command calls.

Am I allowed to use prepared statements with a SELECT query call in the same transaction as INSERT calls as long as nothing besides the values are changed in the SQLiteCommand.CommandText values or is there a different way I need to approach this?

Comment: if you are looking for some sort of result lets say records affected.. assign an Interger variable to the command.ExecuteNonQuery, then check the Integer result.. if something do something else... is this what you are looking for..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a `SELECT` command using prepared statements, but you'll have to create one more `SQLiteCommand` object.

Comment: Do I have to keep on nesting using clauses to do so or is there a syntax for doing a single using clause with several objects at once?

Comment: @grg-n-sox you can have more than one object (but only of the same type) in the using clause; read this for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx